# R Shiny: Reactive DF, filtered according to a reactive nested IF statement

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, nested-if

I am trying to create an app that takes an input file and allows users to ***filter it by applying multiple conditions and picking keywords to look for in selected columns***.

**The filtering logic:**

1. Enter keywords (separated by comma) in textInput widget; through selectInput, pick columns to check if such keywords appear in either of them
2. AFTER that apply another pair of textInput+selectInput condition with AND or OR logic
3. AFTER that EXCLUDE rows containing keywords in selected columns from the 3rd filter.

I am attaching the mtcars example. I created the UI and server code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(gridExtra)
library(gdata)
library(data.table)

df<- as.data.table(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("example"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        #WELL 1. KEYS FILTER
        wellPanel(textInput("keys1", label = h3("Enter keywords separated by     comma:"), placeholder = "Enter text..."),
                  selectInput("cols1", "Select variables:", choices=colnames(df), multiple=T)),

        #AND/OR SELECTOR CONNECTING 1st AND 2nd FILTERS
        radioButtons(inputId="and_or",
                     label="",
                     c("AND"="&", 
                       "OR"="|"),
                     selected="&", inline=T),

        #WELL 2. KEYS2 FILTER
        wellPanel(textInput("keys2", label = h3("Enter keywords separated by comma:"), placeholder = "Enter text..."),
                  selectInput("cols2", "Select variables:", choices=colnames(df), multiple=T)),

        #WELL 3. EXCLUDER FILTER
        wellPanel(textInput("excluders", label = h3("Enter keywords to exclude separated by comma:"), placeholder = "Enter text..."),
                  selectInput("cols_excl", "Select variables:", choices=colnames(df), multiple=T)),
        actionButton("keys_button", "Filter"), 
        width=3),

      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("summary"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )
   )
)



server <- function(input, output) {

  #FILTER_INDEX1
  keys_vector1 <- reactive({
    paste0(unlist(trim(strsplit(input$keys1,","))), collapse = "|")
  })
  keys_index1 <- reactive({
    which(!!rowSums(sapply(df[input$cols1], grepl, pattern = keys_vector1(),     ignore.case = TRUE)))
  })

  #FILTER_INDEX2
  keys_vector2 <- reactive({
    paste0(unlist(trim(strsplit(input$keys2,","))), collapse = "|")
  })
  keys_index2 <- reactive({
    which(!!rowSums(sapply(df[input$cols2], grepl, pattern = keys_vector2(), ignore.case = TRUE)))
 })

  #FILTER_INDEX2
  keys_vector3 <- reactive({
    paste0(unlist(trim(strsplit(input$excluders,","))), collapse = "|")
  })
  keys_index3 <- reactive({
    which(!!rowSums(sapply(df[input$cols_excl], grepl, pattern = keys_vector3(), ignore.case = TRUE)))
  })   



#SUMMARY TABLE  
  output$summary<- renderTable({
        df%>%
    summarize("Number of observations"=n())
  })

#FILTERED DATATABLE
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(df[,], options = list(searching = FALSE))
  })


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Which results in the following:
[image]

I am now struggling to get the Data frame to filter according to the 3 consecutive user inputs.

**Here is the example of what i would like to do:**

**Filter 1:** filter rows which contain number "4" (Entering to `input$keys1`) in "carb" or "gear" columns (Chosen through `input$cols1`)

**Filter 2:** to the resulting dataset, add rows that also contan "0" in "am" column (Entering data to `input$keys2` , `input$cols2` and picking OR in `input$and_or`)

**Filter 3:** from the resulting dataset, exclude rows that contain "Mazda" in "rm" column (By entering data in `input$keys3` and `input$cols3`)

I am thinking it can be done by storing each filter's result as an index vector, then applying intersection/unit to them according to the selected AND/OR radio button.

Ideally, i would like run the filters only after pressing the actionButton "Filter". I am also planning to store the filtered dataframe as a reactive object to download and summarize with plots.

I would really appreciate is someone had an idea/hint of how this rule can be implemented.

Thanks in advance! :)